# twitter share button doesn't count properly

Tags: javascript, twitter, share

I tried to change my ip then share it again but still doesn't count.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<title>:: my test ::</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>

</body>
</html>
```

someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the JavaScript under the anchor tag.

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id))
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

as described at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button